# PHP correcting datetime displaying by calling mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have just get into problem solving one puzzle. So let me explain, I have table that looks like that:

```
 - ID: 0 | USERNAME: SOMETHING1 | DAY: 1 | START: 20:00 | END: 21:00 | STATUS: 0 |
 - ID: 1 | USERNAME: SOMETHING2 | DAY: 3 | START: 18:00 | END: 20:00 | STATUS: 0 |
 - ID: 2 | USERNAME: SOMETHING3 | DAY: 0 | START: 19:00 | END: 21:00 | STATUS: 0 |
 - ID: 3 | USERNAME: SOMETHING4 | DAY: 1 | START: 21:00 | END: 23:00 | STATUS: 0 |
```

database is created to radio website. Homepage on website displays: Current audition (who is playing now on radio) and next audition: here is what am trying to display. Shorten (Name, start time, end time) I want to display auditions of "today" but closest to current time. If audition start time is higher than current time skip to next one. If there aren't any auditions for "today" skip and display audition for next day and all that loops with 7 days.

For reading values am using:
`$currentDay=date("w"); $currentTime=date("H:i");` and array that will change number of day to text.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What keeps you from checking anything about the "same day" (however that is defined)? How is this related to HTML? And what do you mean by "auditions"?

Comment: @NicoHaase database is created to radio website. Homepage on website displays: Current audition (who is playing now on radio) and next audition: here is what am trying to display. Shorten (Name, start time, end time) I want to display auditions of "today" but closest to current time. If there aren't any auditions for "today" skip and display audition for next day and all that loops. Hope it does make sense.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase done, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As you have the value for current day and time you can try executing mysql query like this

```
$currentDay = date("w");
$currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `puzzle` WHERE `DAY` >= ".$currentDay." AND STATUS = 0 
order by `DAY` ASC, ABS(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE(),`START`) - '".$currentDateTime."') ASC LIMIT 1";

// Now Execute the $sql as with you framework , CMS , custom PHP whatever you are using .
// Also change the $sql query also as per your requirement , your question wasn't clear enough to understand .
```

***For Example I have tried this query and it works fine for my test case***

```
SELECT * FROM `puzzle` WHERE `DAY` >= 3 AND STATUS = 0 order by `DAY` ASC, ABS(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE(),`START`) - '2022-02-02 10:10') ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That won't work either. Lets say about auditions. Where in database at same day could be more than one, am trying to echo one in same day and the closest one to current time but if there is none in that day I want to echo for next day and closest to time.

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: Please do not recommend the usage of insecure database queries. String concatenation should not be used to build an SQL query, as this makes the query vulnerable for SQL injection

Comment: @IshaqueJaved I'll try it, if any error Ill message you back. Thank you

Comment: @IshaqueJaved Just one more what if lets say audition is already playing how would I skipp to next one? I meant like its same day but current time is > than start value.

Comment: @lance just add another and where clause which state START > current time like this 

SELECT * FROM `puzzle` WHERE `DAY` >= 3 AND START > '10:48' AND STATUS = 0 order by `DAY` ASC, ABS(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE(),`START`) - '2022-02-02 10:10') ASC

Please select my answer as correct or upvote it as it seems it's correct as per your question. Other clauses you haven't added in the main question.

Comment: @IshaqueJaved just an update of your query. Unfortunately it doesn't work properly, exactly I mean if there is nothing for one of day in week then it doesn't skip that day.